# Example of subclassing string.Template in Python?

Tags: python, stringtemplate

I haven't been able to find a good example of subclassing string.Template in Python, even though I've seen multiple references to doing so in documentation.

Are there any examples of this on the web?

I want to change the $ to be a different character and maybe change the regex for identifiers.

Comment: One note is that you shouldn't attempt to do this in Cython.  It doesn't work.  I'm not sure of the reason.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html):

> Advanced usage: you can derive
>   subclasses of Template to customize
>   the placeholder syntax, delimiter
>   character, or the entire regular
>   expression used to parse template
>   strings. To do this, you can override
>   these class attributes:
>
> - delimiter – This is the literal string describing a placeholder
>     introducing delimiter. The default
>     value $. Note that this should not be
>     a regular expression, as the
>     implementation will call re.escape()
>     on this string as needed.
> - idpattern – This is the regular expression describing the pattern for
>     non-braced placeholders (the braces
>     will be added automatically as
>     appropriate). The default value is the
>     regular expression [_a-z][_a-z0-9]*.

Example:

```
from string import Template

class MyTemplate(Template):
    delimiter = '#'
    idpattern = r'[a-z][_a-z0-9]*'

>>> s = MyTemplate('#who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes $what'
```

---

In python 3:

> *New in version 3.2.*
>
> Alternatively, you can provide the entire regular expression pattern
>   by overriding the class attribute pattern. If you do this, the value
>   must be a regular expression object with four named capturing groups.
>   The capturing groups correspond to the rules given above, along with
>   the invalid placeholder rule:
>
> - escaped – This group matches the escape sequence, e.g. $$, in the default pattern.
> - named – This group matches the unbraced placeholder name; it should not include the delimiter in capturing group.
> - braced – This group matches the brace enclosed placeholder name; it should not include either the delimiter or braces in the capturing
>     group.
> - invalid – This group matches any other delimiter pattern (usually a single delimiter), and it should appear last in the regular
>     expression.

Example:

```
from string import Template
import re

class TemplateClone(Template):
    delimiter = '$'
    pattern = r'''
    \$(?:
      (?P<escaped>\$) |   # Escape sequence of two delimiters
      (?P<named>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)      |   # delimiter and a Python identifier
      {(?P<braced>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)}   |   # delimiter and a braced identifier
      (?P<invalid>)              # Other ill-formed delimiter exprs
    )
    '''

class TemplateAlternative(Template):
    delimiter = '[-'
    pattern = r'''
    \[-(?:
       (?P<escaped>-) |            # Expression [-- will become [-
       (?P<named>[^\[\]\n-]+)-\] | # -, [, ], and \n can't be used in names
       \b\B(?P<braced>) |          # Braced names disabled
       (?P<invalid>)               #
    )
    '''

>>> t = TemplateClone("$hi sir")
>>> t.substitute({"hi": "hello"})
'hello sir'

>>> ta = TemplateAlternative("[-hi-] sir")
>>> ta.substitute({"hi": "have a nice day"})
'have a nice day sir'
>>> ta = TemplateAlternative("[--[-hi-]-]")
>>> ta.substitute({"hi": "have a nice day"})
'[-have a nice day-]'
```

Apparently it is also possible to just omit any of the regex groups `escaped`, `named`, `braced` or `invalid` to disable it.

Comment: do you know how this happens in the background? in other words, how is delimeter being replaced with '#'?

Comment: @slopeofhope this sounds like a separate question to me.